# Existence of a real structure on a complex vector space

Tags: vector-spaces, involutions

As defined on Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_structure) and [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reality_structure), a real structure on a complex vector space is an antilinear involution $\sigma: V\to V$ such that

- $\sigma^2=id_V$
- $\sigma(\lambda x)=\bar\lambda \sigma(x)$.

**My question is** : does it exist on every complex vector space ?

If $V$ has a basis $\{e_i\}_{i\in I}$, I can build this one :

$$\sigma(\sum_{i\in I}\lambda_i e_i)=\sum_{i\in I}\bar\lambda_i e_i$$

But the existence of a basis requires the axiom of choice, and I suspect that there should exist a more direct proof for the existence of a real structure.

**Context** My ultimate purpose is to prove the [One-dimensional dominated extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem#Proof) in the complex case.

Comment: Are you sure you want $\sigma^2 = \sigma$ and not $\sigma^2 = \operatorname{id}_V$?

Comment: @BastiaanCnossen You're right, thanks. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd argue that your formula $\sigma(\sum_{i\in I}\lambda_i e_i)=\sum_{i\in I}\bar\lambda_i e_i$ is already an incredibly direct proof of the existence of such a structure.

Second, I don't think there is a 'canonical choice' for $\sigma$ that does not rely on choosing a basis. For example, if $V = \mathbb{C}$, one could consider either of
$$\sigma_1(\mu) = \overline{\mu}$$
or
$$\sigma_2(\mu) = -\overline{\mu}.$$
Both are real structures on $\mathbb{C}$, but they are not the same.

Essentially you have to choose in $V$ a 'real' direction and an 'imaginary' direction, but before choosing a basis there is no canonical way to do so. (The $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ essentially correspond to choosing either $1$ or $i$ as a complex basis of $\mathbb{C}$.)